# Injection of JavaScript Functions Into a UIWebView Not working always

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I am working with a webapp in iPhone and I have problem with calling native methods from JavaScript.

I need a value which is in my `viewController` class, so that I am calling native method by using `window.location` and in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` I can find which value is needed then I will send that value by using `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:userId];`

Based on this value, I need to call web services in native code. This time `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is not firing. 
i.e simply ***"JS -> Native -> JS -> Native"*** in this case webView delegate not firing.

Would you please give me a solution for this.

Comment: could you post some code? perhaps on `webView` delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running **web.html** stored in Resource.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"web" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView loadHTMLString:jsCode baseURL:nil];
```

in **web.html**, in body, you should have `onload()`, that will fire after `webView` start.

```
<html> <body> <head>

<script>

function anyFunction(){
    window.location='testing123';
}

</script>

</head><body onload="anyFunction();">
</body></html>
```

from there, you should be able to grab "testing123".

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSString *data = [[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([data isEqualToString:@"testing123"])
        NSLog(@"value received");
}
```